# Create a list of all the lists whose entries are in a range in Python

Tags: python, list

How could we do to create the list of all the lists of length 57 whose entries are 5, 6 or 7 ?

Is there a short way to do this ?

**[Update]** I'm looking for a piece of code that create the list of length 3^57 which consists of all the lists of length 57 whose entries are 5, 6 or 7.

Comment: can you update your question with some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Can you give us any examples of such a list?

Comment: An example is [5, 6, 7, 7, 5, ..., 5, 7, 6] (there are 57 entries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the product of `[5, 6, 7]` with itself, 57 times?

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does that for you:

```
from itertools import product

for combination in product([5, 6, 7], repeat=57):
    print combination
```

This will take a while to print all output, however. It'll eventually print all 3 ** 57 == 1570042899082081611640534563 possible combinations.

Don't try and create a single list with all possible combinations, however. On a 64-bit machine *one* of these lists takes 528 bytes, so all lists together take roughly 685719 zetabytes (1 zetabyte is 1024 ** 8 bytes) of memory. Technology isn't that far along yet.

Comment: and on my laptop it will take about 1.7e+20 days to complete